# Fix current dir in ZSH prompt with correct case

Tags: ubuntu, zsh, macos

I've got to following config for case/completion in the **.zshrc** on a Ubuntu server :

```
autoload -Uz compinit
compinit
autoload colors zsh/terminfo
colors
unsetopt menu_complete
unsetopt flowcontrol
setopt correct
setopt auto_menu
setopt always_to_end
zstyle ':completion:*' completer _expand _complete _correct _approximate
zstyle ':completion:*' format "%{${fg[green]}%}%d%{${fg[default]}%}"
zstyle ':completion:*' menu select; zstyle ':completion:*' group-name ''
zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list 'm:{a-zA-Z-_}={A-Za-z_-}' 'r:|=*' 'l:|=* r:|=*'
source /etc/zsh_command_not_found
source ~/.Scripts/zsh-syntax-highlighting/zsh-syntax-highlighting.zsh
```

Somewhere in the PROMPT there is **%d** to show current dir.

On a mac(where the .zshrc) is same doing **cd desktop** corrects to **cd Desktop** and works, but the prompt will display **/Users/me/desktop** and not /**Users/me/Desktop**

For some reason the case insensitivity setting doesn't seem to work on Ubuntu.
What are the recommended settings? And how can i make the **PROMPT** reflect correct case of current dir?

Thanks !

[image]
[image]

Comment: `For some reason…` – Isn't this because HFS is case-insensitive and the filesystem you use on Ubuntu is case-sensitive?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski it's formated as a case sensitive APFS